# Ubuntu can't set IP to static

Tags: networking, wireless, ip, static-ip

Despite my greatest efforts I failed to set my destinated IP on my Ubuntu machine.
I did the following:

This is my ifconfig result:

```
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:f9:03:a1  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:57143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:57143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:5520637 (5.5 MB)  TX bytes:5520637 (5.5 MB)

wlp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:19:34:08:26:63  
          inet addr:192.168.200.3  Bcast:192.168.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::adac:3e50:1835:2e22/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:120810 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:86941 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:65485971 (65.4 MB)  TX bytes:15414822 (15.4 MB)
```

On every tutorial and post I have found the device was called eth0 instead of my wlp5s0, but I switched eth0 with my wlp5s0 in tutorials.

This is my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo wlp5s0
iface lo inet loopback

iface wlp5s0 inet static
address 192.168.200.32
gateway 192.168.200.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

So my address should be "192.168.200.32" after restart, but after restarting:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service networking restart
sudo service resolvconf restart
```

there is no change in ifconfig output.

---

ADDITIONAL INFO, MAY BE NEEDED:

output of `ip route show`

```
default via 192.168.200.1 dev wlp5s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp5s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.200.0/24 dev wlp5s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.200.3  metric 600
```

Output of `ifconfig wlp5s0 | grep Mask` for mask:

```
inet addr:192.168.200.3  Bcast:192.168.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

**I am connecting wirelessly.**

---

When I used network manager it worked for a while, but after a couple of hours I get:

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG
```

when trying to access any website.

Suggested `sudo reslovconf -u` have no effect on this problem.

After I change my DNS servers in any way I get:
[image: my error]

[image: my network manager]

Comment: Is this a server or are you not using Network manager?  You can set up static IP's in Network Manager

Comment: I think the interface *must* be getting the IP via NetworkManager, since your interface stanza on its own would not be enough to establish a wireless connection (you would need to include at least a target SSID and possibly a password or key). Since you're running NetworkManager, then you really should use that IMHO.

Comment: switched to network manager and it works fine. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I think you should add the line `auto wlp5s0` before the ifdown line as shown here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html. But this is better for servers, if you are using the gnome network manager better delete everything except `# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)    
auto lo wlp5s0    
iface lo inet loopback`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Network Manager GUI to set up your static IP
[image]

This is what my Network Manager settings look like using a static IP

But set your address to 192.168.200.32 and set the gateway to 192.168.200.1

Comment: I end up getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG when trying to access websites after that (oddly enough I can use skype to talk with my friends). I updated main question with details.

Comment: It might be in conflict because of the additions you made to /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: I changed it back to the state it was before.

Comment: Your DNS would have to be 192.168.200.1 also

Comment: I know, but I keep getting error I showed in post when trying to save dns server

Comment: Does `dpkg -l | grep networkmanager` show networkmanager-qt?

Comment: yes, it shows:

`ii  libkf5networkmanagerqt6                         5.18.0-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Qt wrapper for NetworkManager - library


ii  plasma-nm                                       4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1                           amd64        Plasma5 networkmanager library.
`

Comment: [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/networkmanager-qt/+bug/1569674) concerning your error

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to connect wirelessly and use `/etc/network/interfaces`, it is necessary to declare the network and password to which you wish to connect:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo wlp5s0
iface lo inet loopback

iface wlp5s0 inet static
    address 192.168.200.32
    gateway 192.168.200.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wpa-ssid <your_router>
    wpa-psk <your_wpa_key>
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Get the system to read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown wlp5s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp5s0
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 192.168.200.1
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

Comment: by <your_router> do you mean SSID?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For example, if your SSID shows in: `sudo iwlist scan` as *ESSID:"nx2.4"*,  then the correct line would be: `wpa-ssid nx2.4`